# Ensuring only the response to the latest (direct) proxy read request is processed

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

In a calendar system I'm developing, a selection of a date fetch events for that date from the server.

The problem is that if the user quickly toggles between dates, sometimes the response for the second request is returned before the response to the first request, causing the store to be populated by the wrong records (that of the first request, ie the wrong date).

I have attempted using `Ext.Ajax.abort()`, but this seems not to work with `direct` calls.

So the question is how do I ensure only the response for the latest request is processed by the proxy?

The solution I came up with is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to derived from the direct proxy class, to ensure such behaviour:

```
/**
 * A proxy class that ensures only the reponse to the last read request is 
 * processed.
 *
 * A quick user actions may result in more than one request sent to the server,
 * but it is possible for the server to return a response to the second request
 * before returning that of the first request. This will mean the the store
 * will be populated with records that do not correspond to the latest user
 * action.
 *
 */

Ext.define('Ext.data.proxy.SerialDirect', {

    extend: 'Ext.data.proxy.Direct',
    alternateClassName: 'Ext.data.DirectSerialProxy',

    alias: 'proxy.serialdirect',

    doRequest: function(operation, callback, scope) {
        this.callParent( arguments );

        // Store the last read request
        if ( operation.request.action == "read" ) {
            this.lastReadRequest = operation.request;
        }
    },

    processResponse: function(success, operation, request, response, callback, scope) {            
        // abort if the request is a read one and does not correspond to the
        // last read request
        if ( request.action == "read" && request != this.lastReadRequest )
            return;

        this.callParent( arguments );
    }
});
```